# Trend router table compatibility

Tags: router-table

I recently bought a Trend CRT/MK3 router table and am trying to choose a router to go with it.
Feature wise the trend t11 looks good because of its ability to have the cut height adjusted through the table whilst inverted. I'm wondering if there are any other routers with this feature that are compatible with this table. The manual lists other compatible routers but the model numbers referenced seem hopelessly out of date and all matches I can find seem to be discontinued.

I can see a Triton router that looks promising but can't see anything about mounting compatibility.

Can anyone who has one of these tables confirm any information?

Comment: Sorry, but shopping questions are off-topic for SE sites, as they age poorly. Take the [tour] to see what I mean. Luckily, though, most router tables just work with most routers. Instead of models you should be searching for router base compatibility. You might be able to [edit] this question into one that inquires about how to figure out base compatibility.

Comment: Of course, you can also just [ask the manufacturer](https://www.sautershop.com/support/index/sFid/16/sInquiry/detail/sOrdernumber/T-CRT-MK3-EURO), as they seem pretty clear that they work with most routers, possibly with add-on kits or drilling some additional holes.

Comment: They do claim to work with 'most routers', but I already have 2 routers that aren't compatible so I don't want to end up with a third. I have tried to do research on the topic but there seems to be very little information published by most manufacturers. Trend talk about support for 'Trend Base Configuration', but nobody else seems to claim to conform to it.

Comment: @jdv, this isn't a shopping question per se. The OP isn't asking for product recommendations but rather about which routers have a given feature, which is no different to a "Which plane can do this job?" type of query.

Comment: @user1111284 the web site for this table has a list of router models that might be more updated than the printed manual. I don't think you are ever going to get an exhaustive answer to this question without contacting the manufacturer. All someone could say is "router X worked" but any change to the model could obviate that. Given this same company sells baseplate adapters there is potentially a 3-way matrix of options, so talking with a human who actually knows is your best bet. I would not trust anyone else's opinion on this.

Comment: The same web info shows all the dimensions, so you basically have to match measurements. For all you know, one of your routers just needs an adapter of some kind and maybe some custom holes drilled and it'll work fine. But you need to consult with someone who actually knows how all of this fits together. At best someone might tell you that one of the 100s of combinations worked for them.